# which type of model in Django for this form of values?

Tags: django

I want to create a model in my Django app for this value, in this value we have ";" :
 `0;-0.0110227457430789;-0.0117428254241928;`

How can help me please?

```
value = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: corige? What do you mean by corige?

Comment: Are you using Postgres? If so, then maybe [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) will be the proper solution (like `ArrayField(models.FloatField(), size=3)`).

Comment: yes i am using postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the maximum length of CharField is 255.
(Every VARCHAR field's maximum length is 255)
If its a string, you can use CharField for that( if the length is not more that 255 )
If the string length can be more than 255, you should use TextField()
(TextField is not stored in VARCHAR type,its stored in BLOB)

[CharField - **max_length** documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#character-fields)
[CharField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield)
[TextField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield)